Javascript exporting multi dimentioanl array results in some values to be empty
I am coding a practice react application in which I am exporting a primitive array with a separate file named data.js
export const data = [
{
    type:"multiple",
    difficulty:"easy",
    category:"Entertainment: Film",
    question:"The Queen song `A Kind Of Magic` is featured in which 1986 film?",        
    correct_answer:"Highlander",
    incorrect_answers:["Flash Gordon","Labyrinth","Howard the Duck"]
    
},
{
    type:"multiple",
    difficulty:"easy",
    category:"Entertainment: Film",
    question:"Who plays Jack Burton in the movie &quot;Big Trouble in Little China?&quot;",
    correct_answer:"Kurt Russell",
    incorrect_answers:["Patrick Swayze","John Cusack","Harrison Ford"]
},
{
    type:"multiple",
    difficulty:"easy",
    category:"Entertainment: Film",
    question:"Which of these films is NOT set in Los Angeles?",
    correct_answer:"RoboCop",
    incorrect_answers:["Blade Runner","The Terminator","Predator 2"]
},
{
    type:"multiple",
    difficulty:"easy",
    category:"Entertainment: Film",
    question:"Who wrote and directed the 1986 film &#039;Platoon&#039;?",
    correct_answer:"Oliver Stone",
    incorrect_answers:["Francis Ford Coppola","Stanley Kubrick","Michael Cimino"]
},
{
    type:"multiple",
    difficulty:"easy",
    category:"Entertainment: Film",
    question:"This movie contains the quote, &quot;I feel the need ... the need for speed!&quot;",
    correct_answer:"Top Gun",
    incorrect_answers:["Days of Thunder","The Color of Money","Cocktail"]
}

]
However when I import the file in my app as follows
import {data} from "./assets/data.jsx"
import Question from "./Question"

console.log(data)

incorrect_answers is empty array

However the strange thing is when I rename incorrect_array: to incorrectArray: then the value is exported correctly. I cannot seem to understand this behavior as I think it should export the array correctly the first time.
Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.
Thank you
Rivi

Your file name is data.js, but you are importing data.jsx. It might be that the application has another file with data.jsx where the field incorrect_answers is empty

Thankx for your comment and response. However it turned out that I have been unknowingly editing the data on a function. I am still struggling to understand sometimes that arrays are referenced so I used to the map method to create a copy. now its working fine thankx
